# ExtJs 4 - How to drag drop the contents of the text (or text area) field?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, extjs4

I have a form panel with several text and text area fields and would like to copy (or move) the text from one field to another by dragging. (The fields itself should stay in place).

ExtJs provides the example, which does almost what I need: [field-to-grid-dd](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/dd/field-to-grid-dd.html).

The problem is that it is now not possible to enter the text into the draggable text field. I assume that's because the 'mousedown' event is intercepted by the Ext.dd.DragZone object, whose method getDragData() initiates the dragging if the mouse is clicked inside the draggable element.

It there a way to put the cursor inside the text field if the user just clicks it without dragging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tell you how to change the ExtJS Example file ([**field-to-grid-dd.js**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/extjs-build/examples/dd/field-to-grid-dd.js)), then you can change your own app codes.

Go to line **148** and comment or **remove** the code below:

```
// i.unselectable();
```

Then go to line **164** and **add** the code below before (or after, it doesn't matter) `e.stopEvent();`:

```
t.focus(); // Add This
e.stopEvent();
```

Of course, you can not select the value of textfield with dragging the mouse, but it does what you want.